# Programming Error: With PhoneNumberField in Django

Tags: python, django

After pip install phone number field on global as well as in virtual env
and importing in the models.py
I am facing programming error.
Details are as follows

DB is POSTGRESQL

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class Agent(models.Model):
    agency_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    prop_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    agency_address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    agency_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    agency_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    contact_nu = PhoneNumberField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.agency_name
```

```
admin.py

@admin.register(Agent)
class AgentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('agency_name', 'prop_name', 'agency_address', 'agency_city', 'agency_country', 'email_address', 'contact_nu')
```

```
Error:

[07/Jun/2021 09:52:34] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5546
Internal Server Error: /admin/rk003/agent/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column rk003_agent.contact_nu does not exist
```

Error at the time of migrate is as follows
During Migration there is no error. Makemigration works fine and create models. The check also dont return any error. Just at the time of migrate below error pops up

```
File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "contact_nu" of relation "rk003_agent" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/rk002/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/rk002/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 244, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 594, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 196, in _alter_field
    super()._alter_field(
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 751, in _alter_field
    self.execute(
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "contact_nu" of relation "rk003_agent" does not exist
```

Thanks

Comment: run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat already done still facing error while doing migrate.. `Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, rk003, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying rk003.0002_auto_20210607_1008...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "guest_id" of relation "rk003_agent" does not exist`

Comment: What error do you get while migrating? [edit] your question and add the _full_ error traceback (The one when you are migrating).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Please check the complete error. It is updated now

Answer (score 0):

Use a CharField, easy to handle yourself and won't cause any excessive errors.

Comment: I have worked with CharField in earlier app. Now want specific field for phone number. Thanks for your reply

Comment: did you get it working? it is literally just a formatted charfield so look at what they handle and rewrite if its still causing issues https://pypi.org/project/django-phonenumber-field/